# Pagination MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm trying to use pagination for a customer table using PHP, MySQL & Bootstrap. I wrote this code:

```
<div class="container mx-auto">
<!--Add class table-responsive for responsive table -->
<table class="table mx-auto">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Zipcode</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Company</th>


    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <ul class="pagination">
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['page'])){

            $previous = $_GET['page'] - 1;
            if($previous = -1 ){
                $previous = 0;
            }
            if($previous = 0){
                echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Previous</a></li>';
            }
            else{
                echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page='. $previous.'">Previous</a></li>';
            }
        }
        $page_max = 10;
        $entriesInDatabase = $database->getData("SELECT count(id) FROM customers");
        $numberOfPages = ceil($entriesInDatabase['count(id)']/$page_max);

        for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPages; $i++){

            echo '<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page='. $i . '">'. $i. '</a></li>';
        }
        if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
            $start = $page * 10;
            $end = ($page + 1) * 10;
            var_dump($start); 
            var_dump($end);
        }
        else{
            $page = 0;
            $start = $page * 10;
            $end = 10;
        }

        $customers = $database->getUsers("SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT $start, $end");

        ?>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php



    foreach($customers as $customer){
        $name = $customer ['name'];
        $surname = $customer['surname'];
        $email = $customer['email'];
        $phone = $customer['phone'];
        $address = $customer['address'];
        $zipcode = $customer['zipcode'];
        $city = $customer['city'];
        $company = $customer['company'];
        $id = $customer['id'];
        echo "<tr>
                <td>$name</td>
                <td>$surname</td>
                <td>$email</td>
                <td>$phone</td>
                <td>$address</td>
                <td>$zipcode</td>
                <td>$city</td>
                <td>$company</td>



              </tr>";
    }
    ?>
```

I want each page to show 10 records from the database so giving a limit to my SQL query. What happends now is the following; page 0 shows 10 records, page 1 shows 20 records, page 2 shows also 20 records but page 9 shows 11 records.

Could anyone help me out fixing this issue?

Comment: I think the secound parameter to `LIMIT` is the amount, so you can just use `... LIMIT $start, 10`, you don't need to specifiy the end index. And if you need an end index for whatever reason why not simply `$end = $start + 10`

Comment: The 2nd number in a `LIMIT` statement is not the **end** but the number of records you want to retrieve - so should always be 10 here.

Comment: `if($previous = -1 )` You need at least double and probably triple equation signs here, or you're evaluating an assignment rather than a mathematical equation. Same goes for `if($previous = 0)`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take care of all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd be better off thinking about the principles of how it works rather than just looking at the code.

Firstly, you need to know:

- How many records are there in the table? You can do that with `COUNT()`
- How many entries to show per page? You may fix this, to say 10 per page, or any number.

You then need to understand how `LIMIT` works. If you do something such as `LIMIT 50, 10` it means use `50` as the starting point ("from the 51st record in the table" - remember the indexes start at `0`) and get the next `10` rows. The latter number, `10`, is the number of rows you want to show per page.

In terms of constructing the links the easiest method is to make the `?page=` parameter in the URL the first value for the `LIMIT` query because this changes per page (e.g. `50` in the example above), where as you know the other number (`10`) is constant. You can produce these links by doing a `ceil` on the number of records in the table, divided by the number of records per page. This will output the appropriate numbers for the URL.

Let's say you had 362 records in your database and wanted to show 10 per page. This would produce the URL's:

```
$per_page = 10;
$records_in_db_table = 362; // You must calculate this from a COUNT() query
$n = ceil($records_in_db_table / $per_page);

for ($x=0; $x<$n; $x++) {
    $page = ($x * $per_page);
    echo '?page=' . $page;
}
```

The above code outputs:

```
?page=0
?page=10
?page=20
?page=30
// ...
?page=360
```

Then you just feed these in to your query's `LIMIT` condition, e.g.

- `?page=10` == `LIMIT 10, 10`
- `?page=20` == `LIMIT 20, 10`
- `?page=30` == `LIMIT 30, 10`
- etc...

It's also worth noting that you don't need to care about what happens if you're trying to `LIMIT` to more records than exist. For example the last URL (`?page=360`) will do `LIMIT 360, 10`. There are only 362 records in your database so you might assume this won't work as there are only 2 records that could be returned from that query. However, it will just return the last 2, no problem.

Equally if you try and use a number which is way beyond the total number of records (`?page=99999` which gives `LIMIT 99999, 10`) it will just return an empty result set, not an error. Some people code things in to do a simple check, e.g.

```
if ((int)$_GET['page'] > $records_in_db_table) { 
    // Display error message
}
```

Remember that you should sanitise `$_GET['page']` or at the very least cast it to an integer. Do not inject anything from `$_GET` directly into your query, and use parameter binding (e.g. PDO) if possible.

You may also want to look at DataTables (https://datatables.net/) since this does a lot of what you need without writing any such code and works well with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that you don't know how the `LIMIT` keyword works.
If you only give it one parameter, it will be interpreted as the maximum number of entries from the query that must be returned.
If you pass it two values, the first will be interpreted as the start offset while the second will still be the maximum amount of returned entries.

In other words, writing `LIMIT 50, 60` - which would happen in your case when preparing the 5th page - will start getting results from the 51th matching entry and will also return the 59 next ones.

If you want to display 10 records per page, hard write 10 as the second `LIMIT` parameter and it should be better.

http://sql.sh/cours/limit

Answer (score 0):

You should ignored the page zero, and try :
start : `($page - 1) * 10;`
end : `$end = 10;`

Comment: I believe it would be a bad idea to keep it that way. Calling that variable end and having it to be static would be semantically wrong. The variable shouldn't be named `$end` in the first place, since its a limit, not an offset.

Comment: @ksjohn you're right I named the variable "numberOfRecords" to avoid confussion the next time !

Comment: @SanderBakker No need for it to be that long, `$limit` is clear enough ;) Besides, that variable doesn't indicate the number of records you'll get but the limit after which records won't get returns from the query.

Comment: @ksjohn Yeah I will use '$limit' then. Btw how can I put my pagination under my table? Just putting the code under will not work because of the variable customers in the foreach loop

Comment: @SanderBakker I've posted an answer please take a look. Might clear some of these things up for you.

Comment: @SanderBakker If you are asking how to integrate a pagination, that should be the topic of another question.

Comment: @ksjohn just i simplified for you.